# Upright letters in enumeration are not set justified

Tags: enumerate, enumitem

I use several enumerations in theorem-environments. The font is italic, but I wanted to set the labels (for which I use letters) upright. I read that I do this via `\normalfont`and it works. But I saw that the labels are not set justified. Here is a picture:
[image]

If we have a closer look, we can see that (b) is set some pixels further to the left left edge:
[image]

I would like to adjust them, and preferable not hardcoded. Is that possible?

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[ngerman, fontsize=11pt, DIV=12 ,BCOR = 10mm, parskip=half-, twoside]{scrbook}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheoremstyle{style:lemma}
{3pt}% Space above
{3pt}% Space below
{\itshape}% Body fonti
{}% Indent amount
{\bfseries}% Theorem head font
{.}% Punctuation after theorem head
{.5em}% Space after theorem head
{}% Theorem head spec (can be left empty, meaning ‘normal’)

\theoremstyle{style:lemma}
    \newtheorem{lemma}[]{Lemma}

\begin{document}
    \begin{lemma}
        There are several points to show. These are

    \begin{enumerate}[label = \normalfont(\alph*)]
        \item $a = b+1$
        \item $\sqrt{n} = 2$
        \item and the third.
    \end{enumerate}
\end{lemma}
\end{document}
```

Comment: you can use the align key (but perhaps need to adapt the label width too, see the documentation).

Comment: The answers are very good, but since none of them have said this explicitly: The in the default output you show, the labels *are* justified — but they’re *right*-justified rather than left-justified (easily checked in your image by a second red line).  This is fairly standard and natural, since it ensures that the space between each item’s label and body is the same, regardless of the width of the label.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using the `enumitem` package with the options `wide=0pt, left=0pt`, it solves the problem of the alignment.

```
\documentclass[ngerman, fontsize=11pt, DIV=12, BCOR=10mm, parskip=half-, twoside]{scrbook}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheoremstyle{style:lemma}
{3pt}% Space above
{3pt}% Space below
{\itshape}% Body font
{}% Indent amount
{\bfseries}% Theorem head font
{.}% Punctuation after theorem head
{.5em}% Space after theorem head
{}% Theorem head spec (can be left empty, meaning ‘normal’)

\theoremstyle{style:lemma}
\newtheorem{lemma}[]{Lemma}

\begin{document}
    \begin{lemma}
        There are several points to show. These are

        \begin{enumerate}[label=\normalfont(\alph*), wide=0pt, left=0pt]
            \item $a = b+1$
            \item $\sqrt{n} = 2$
            \item and the third.
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{lemma}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Well, with the two options `wide=0pt, left=0pt` you suggest, it appears that if an enumerated item runs in two lines then the second line starts where the label above, which is usually not desirable.

Answer (score 15):

[`enumitem`](//ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) provides the `align` key, which you can set to `left` to have the enumeration left-aligned. However, this may require some adjustment of the other horizontal list measurements as well. The example below tries to replicate the output so they're similar, the latter one just adding `align=left` in the mix.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}

\begin{document}

\begin{lemma}
There are several points to show. These are
\begin{enumerate}[label=\normalfont(\alph*)]
  \item $a = b + 1$
  \item $\sqrt{n} = 2$
  \item and the third.
\end{enumerate}
\end{lemma}

\begin{lemma}
There are several points to show. These are
\begin{enumerate}[label=\normalfont(\alph*),align=left,labelwidth=1em,labelindent=0.8em,labelsep=0.25em,leftmargin=*]
  \item $a = b + 1$
  \item $\sqrt{n} = 2$
  \item and the third.
\end{enumerate}
\end{lemma}

\end{document}
```

You can create a list specifically for this by adding

```
\newlist{theoremenum}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[theoremenum]{%
  label=\normalfont(\alph*),
  align=left,
  labelwidth=1em,
  labelindent=0.8em,
  labelsep=0.25em,
  leftmargin=*
}
```

to your preamble. This allows you to use

```
\begin{theoremenum}
  \item ...
  \item ...
  ...
\end{theoremenum}
```

wherever you need that kind of enumeration/formatting.